# How to drag a layer from ArcMap Add-in into its MXD?

Tags: arcobjects, arcmap, c#, add-in

I have a simple ArcMap Add-in that displays all featureclass names in a database inside of a ListBox.  If I select a name or multiple names in the listbox, how can I drag and drop it in ArcMap?  Just to give a quick summary, the purpose of this add-in is because the database has encrypted names and I have to show the "friendly names" in the ListBox control so I will use a special refrence table in SQL to populate the listbox with the friendly names.

Comment: Encrypted names? Can you give an example?

Comment: @blah238 sorry I meant ArcMap not Catalog.  I've corrected my question and tags.

Comment: What? That wasn't my question at all. What do you mean by "encrypted names"?

Comment: Wells Featureclass = G01P01L0023 in sde

Comment: Well that's weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just an idea and an alternative to drag 'n' drop. It sounds like you have a list box on a form that is being populated with friendly names. I'm guessing these will be simply text entries? Instead of trying to drag 'n' drop why not have a button that when clicked reads the selected items (your table names) in the list box, connects to the workspace and loads them into the map?

I would image that would be easier to implement unless drag 'n' drop is specifically required?

Comment: yes that approach does sound easier.  if I were to use a button to load the layers into arcmap how do I get access to the activeview?

Comment: In 10.1 VB .net it would be: Dim pMXDocument As IMxDocument pMXDocument = My.ArcMap.Document Dim pMap As IMap pMap = pMXDocument.FocusMap

Comment: Thanks this worked for me and I was able to add layers from my addin to my arcmap session

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to implement [IGxObject](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/0014/00140000012n000000.htm) and display your objects in a [GxContentsView](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/GxContentsViewClass_Class/00150000003p000000/). See the [Catalog](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/Overview/0014000001tt000000/) and [CatalogUI](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/Overview/00150000016v000000/) library overviews.

Another possibility might be to use the [`IDataObjectHelper`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/0043/004300000032000000.htm). See Richie Carmichael's [blog post](http://kiwigis.blogspot.com/2009/05/drag-and-drop-in-arcgis-desktop.html) on this topic.